# has_many or HABTM

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This question has been asked numerous times but I can't project any of the answers to my specific situation, so here goes.

I have an `events`, `options` and a `templates` table. There is also a join table called `events_templates` with the fields:

- option_id
- template_id
- event_id

An event has **one** template per option. But obviously can have many templates because there are multiple options.

Currently my `event` model has the method

`has_many :templates, class_name: "EventsTemplate"`

Question is, is this the right setup or should I use HABTM?

THANKS so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should set this up a bit different, based on the requirements you specified.

```
has_many :templates, class_name: "EventsTemplate"
```

This won't work the way you want it to. It will give event an association templates, but calling that association will return EventTemplates instead.

You probably want to set this up using a `through` association.

```
class EventTemplate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :option
  belongs_to :template
  belongs_to :event
end

class Event
  has_many :event_templates
  has_many :templates, through: :event_templates
end
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the solution I came up with as well :) Now I can simply use `Event.event_templates.option` and `Event.templates`

Comment: Good to see your solution confirmed :)